Hello for Business fails to validate KDC certificate. Resolved after reissuing certificate revocation list. Trying to understand why
I've been investigating an issue on my notebook where logging in with my Hello for Business credentials stopped working and started throwing an error. I was able to resolve after weeks of troubleshooting but I don't know why I had to fix it this way and if there's a better way.
We have a 2-tier Active Directory Certificate Authority and separate IIS server for publishing our Certificate Revocation List. We use hybrid joined devices and WHfB is configured using key trust.
The issue started with a login error when using WHfB credentials:
Sign-in failed. Contact your system administrator and tell them that the KDC certificate could not be validated. Additional information may be available in the system event log.
I reviewed online blogs and Microsoft articles that cover the usual points of the domain controller certificate not being valid or missing extended key usage config (i.e. KDC Authentication). Everything was OK there.
There were also system event logs on my notebook with this failure:
Event ID 9, Source: Security-Kerberos.
The client has failed to validate the domain controller certificate for <domain controller>. The following error was returned from the certificate validation process: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
I reviewed our CA configuration, revocation settings and CRL IIS settings to confirm these were working, and the CRL was resolvable and accessible. Everything worked when tested in a browser so it appeared the CRL was online. Contrary to what Event ID 9 was saying.
I started running packet captures and would lock the notebook and attempt WHfB authentication.
I was able to see the notebook attempt to retrieve the CRL:
GET /CertEnroll/CertAuthorityRoot.crl HTTP/1.1
The IIS server hosting the CRL would return a 304 Not Modified response:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
My understanding is that 304 is what the IIS server returns if the file hasn't changed and directs the requesting device to look at cached files.
My take away is my notebook was trying to get the CRL at login, but the IIS server was telling my notebook that it doesn't need it because it hasn't been modified. So my notebook assumed it couldn't contact the server.
My fix was to boot our offline CA, publishing a new CRL file and place it in our CRL IIS server. When my notebook next tried to authenticate again, the IIS server happily provided it.
I would like to understand why my notebook suddenly needed the CRL file again after working for so long and then why the IIS server refused to let my PC download it again.
After reissuing the CRL file I found the certutil command for listing cached URLs:
certutil -urlcache CRL
I wonder if there was some corrupt CRL but no chance to check that now.
Anyone else had something similar occur?

I would really like to understand why my notebook suddenly needed the CRL file again after working for so long How long?

Not 100% sure but it would have been over 6 months.

The most apparent cause is expired CRL.

You have offline root CA (which cannot automatically publish CRLs to distribution points)
Things started to work after booting offline CA and publishing CRL

This suggests that previous CRL was expired. Expired CRLs render the same error message (revocation is offline).
In order to avoid this issue in future, you have to establish offline CA CRL monitoring and alerting, so you get notifications on about to expire CRLs in advance and implement a process that you execute in order to renew CRL in distribution points.

Thanks, Crypt32. I should have mentioned that the CRL wasn't due for its next update until 2028. So it looked like it still had 4 years to go.

If CRL replacement fixed issue, then CRL wasn't right. There is no magic. Unfortunately, it is impossible to tell what exactly happened for you, because you fixed it and no way to reproduce exactly same condition. Unless you have a full environment backup to restore in test environment.

@BeardedAdmin: CRL is expected to change and be reissued and recreated, possibly frequently. What is your process for updating the CRL? And how is it linked to an offline host? Also, does IIS still return the 304 for the new CRL? Any system anywhere will fail completely if any component of the certificate service doesn't work. That's why some organizations mirror CRLs, so the wheels don't fall off because a file isn't available.

This is for our enterprise root. The CRL for the root was updating every 10 years. It was set to update in 2028. For this offline root, we were just manually publishing the CRL and copying to the IIS server which I did here. I'm sure there's better ways to handle it. I'll confirm if 304 responses are still being sent.

For the root CA crl file, there are currently no 304 events but I may need to give it time. For what it's worth, when I was getting 304 events for the root CA crl file, other devices using a different certificate template got 200 events when querying the same root CA crl.

HTTP 304 is just fine. It is pre-fetch functionality. Clients initially cache CRL locally and then periodically poll web server for changes, they pass existing CRL E-tag value and if server has the same CRL, then it responds with HTTP 304, no new file version is available, clients continue to use cached CRL.

@BeardedAdmin: now that I've thought about it, it seems like even disabling CRL checking may not fix this. That's unfortunate because it's common for MFA to disable CRL checks if it isn't available. However, it may not prevent a problem if the client is in contact with the CDP. There probably needs to be a broader flag like "ignore CRL problems" (everything but a positive revocation) to compensate for the flawed design and implementation. Without that, this service may be unsuitable for production usage.

I have seen this problem because of laptop is changing network (DirectAcess VPN) and during a short period of time the CRL list will not work because of network interruption. If the enduser wait a little until DA is online it will work.

This seems a likely cause. CRL access is frequently problematic with certificate based MFA. Disabling CRLs for MFA is not uncommon, due to the recovery implications.

@GregAskew, Disabling CRLs for MFA is not uncommon Do you have any info or guides handy on how to do this that I could review?
